# Servlet "не видит" атрибут

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Создаю сервлет, в классе добавляю в request атрибуты,

```
request.setAttribute("listStrings", list);
request.setAttribute("stringTest", str);
```

в jsp их вывожу. Выводит все нормально. Но, сам jsp не видит этих переменных-атрибутов, их надо вводить вручную. Соответственно, если работает со списком объектов, то прописывать приходится все вручную.

Как это можно исправить ?

Исходники, если кому надо. Проект простейший, тестовый.
https://github.com/LHaart/jstlTest

Comment: ***в jsp их вывожу. Выводит все нормально.*** Значит видит нормально. Вопрос вообще не понял.

Comment: Скажем так, когда вы в мейне обращаетесь к объекту, вы нажимаете точку и выбираете метод. Это стандартный быстрый набор в ide, так вот, в этом случае, в jsp он не работает, jsp просто не видит что это за переменная. Я делал нечто похожее c spring web mvc, там все прекрасно работало. Я знаю что и тут можно сделать, я просто не знаю как.

Comment: Возможно это просто ide не может сопоставить эти переменные. У меня как раз со spring так получается, но если всё прописать руками не полагаясь на ide. Сам пока так же мучаюсь.

Comment: Да, если все вручную прописать, работает. Просто неудобно. Думал проблема известная, хоть и не нашел ответ через упорный поиск в гугле. Не знаю как правильно сформировать вопрос. Тут видимо тоже промахнулся, никто не отвечает)

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=2&clid=1955454&win=236&msid=1503931102.29026.22890.5042&text=idea%20can%20not%20resolve%20variable%20jsp проблема не первой свежести.

Comment: Ага, через аннотацию получается. Понятно. Вынесите свой последний коммент как ответ. помечу как полезный.

<%--@elvariable id="listMeals" type="java.util.List<ru.javawebinar.topjava.model.MealWithExceed>"--%>

И так для каждой переменной, но зато работает.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694392/intellij-not-resolving-el-variables-within-jsp-code-inspection-or-autocomplete

> через аннотацию получается. Понятно.  <%--@elvariable id="listMeals" type="java.util.List"--%> И так для каждой переменной, но зато работает.

https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=2&clid=1955454&win=236&msid=1503931102.29026.22890.5042&text=idea%20can%20not%20resolve%20variable%20jsp - проблема не первой свежести.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: Если что, ответ нашелся тут. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694392/intellij-not-resolving-el-variables-within-jsp-code-inspection-or-autocomplete  А автор не виноват, он же не знает где я бродил по ссылкам.

Comment: @Haart , добавил твою ссылку, ну а за минусы не переживай - это синдром вахтера. Можно показать свою значимость минусом при этом ничего не сделав.